# setting UIlabel property-name from a dictionary

Tags: ios, properties, uilabel

I have came across a very interesting problem. I have a UILabel and a number of the label properties. Corresponding to each property, there is a value that is to be set for the label. This property-value thing is in a dictionary (as key-value pair). Lets say, there is a key-value pair as "text":"abc" (here text is my key and abc is the corresponding text that has to be set). I dont want to use myLabel.text = ; just like the value here can come from any array or nsstring, I want the property also to be dynamic. Here is a sample of what I want:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tryDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[tryDict setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"text"];
UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc]init];
NSArray *allKeys = [tryDict allKeys];
NSArray *allValues = [tryDict allValues];
NSSTring *textProp = [allKeys objectAtIndex:0];
lblName.textProp = [allValues objectAtIndex:0]; // giving an error since textProp is not a UIlabel property.
```

Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[lblName setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:tryDict]` this method is just what you need.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Can you help me with one more thing? I want the name of the label (lblName in above case) to be coming from an array or an NSString variable. Is it possible?

Comment: You can find something in Objective-C Runtime Reference. But i think you'd better have a dictionary containing UILables with keys like `lblName`.